# Typescript object possibly null even when properly checked

Tags: typescript

I am using typescript in my project and trying to compare a value inside the object with another value, but I cannot seem to get past typescript's "Object possibly null" error:

[image: I started out with trying op cha]

I have tried restarting the TS server, but it does not seem to do it.

Comment: It looks like problem is in popperRef type. How is it defined in your code. Usually you should do some like this **const bodyRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);**

Comment: Yes, that is what I have inside that's the declaration that I have

Comment: Is this all of your code? This normally happens if you are using a type guard between the if statement and the usage, [for example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChkTkQ5MIAuZAZzClAHMBuY0nCJgOQFdMARtAD8NEPyFQA2gF02pZAGtQAExr1GIVoQC+hQqEixEKACIB7JsggAPSCBW00GbHiILgtAOLnzKgELmAJ40Ar6ccCBseoQwvCAIYMDmIMieFkwAFHA06Fi4AJQ0cGlOGQTsJFAQYLxQqXAAdMoOyAC8HcgA5CqWXdH6cQlJKcgw2bkuhRUeMMjZjZw8EtAFMwqkwHOZ6ZbZBWvuG8dNS3yC0I0ADry0ABaZACwF8sfIegp6OkA)

Comment: It looks like all function is needed to say what going on. It looks like problem is in popperRef definition, but I should see it

Answer (score -1):

You should also check whether `popperRef` has a property `current`, which itself should have a property `popper`.

```js
if( popperRef ) {
  if( popperRef.hasOwnProperty('current') ) {
    if( popperRef.current.hasOwnProperty('popper') ) {
      if( popperRef.current.popper !== event.target ) {
        // ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am afraid that it is not that. Still getting the same complaint.